# Generic class method returns its own type as a template parameter

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I'm designing a set of generic classes that hold `Document` objects within `Folder` objects:

```
// Folder, which holds zero or more documents
public interface Folder<DocType extends Document>
{
    // Locate matching documents within the folder
    public ArrayList<DocType> findDocuments(...);
    ...
}

// Document, contained within a folder
public interface Document
{
    // Retrieve the parent folder
    public Folder getFolder();    // Not correct
    ...
}
```

These classes are then extended for the actual implementation of the folder and document types. The trouble is that the `Document.getFolder()` method needs to return an object of type `Folder<DocType>`, where `DocType` is the actual implementation type of `Document`. Which means that the method needs to know what its own concrete class type is.

So my question is, should the `Document` class be declared instead like this:

```
// Document, contained within a Folder
public interface Document<DocType extends Document>
{
    // Retrieve the parent folder
    public Folder<DocType> getFolder();
    ...
}
```

Or is there a simpler way to do this? The code above requires concrete implementations to look like this:

```
public class MyFolder
    implements Folder<MyDocument>
{ ... }

public class MyDocument
    implements Document<MyDocument>
{ ... }
```

It's the `Document<MyDocument>` part that seems a bit strange to me; is it really necessary?

*(Apologies if this is a duplicate; I couldn't find the exact answer I was looking for in the archives.)*

**ADDENDUM**

The original code above used `ArrayList<DocType>`, but like several posters have pointed out, I'd be better off returning a `List`, e.g.:

```
    public List<DocType> findDocuments(...);
```

(That method was not crucial to my problem, and my actual API returns an `Iterator`, so I just used the first thing that came to mind in order to simplify the question.)

Comment: Note: use interfaces (List) not implementation types (ArrayList) for return values, where possible.

Comment: Generics can be a bit of a pain sometimes. But in this case, not sure I'd want to use them. Any reason why you wouldn't be happy if have Folder just returns a List of Documents and leave it at that?

Comment: Can a `Folder` really only contain one type of `Document`? (This is what your current generic interface suggests.)

Comment: @Jeffrey: Yes, the design is that a specific `Folder` type contains a specific `Document` type. Obviously, the document and folder classes can be further subclassed if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems an aedequate way to adress your requirements, and no, there is no simpler way to express the same (in particular, Java has no syntax to constrain a type parameter to the type of `this`).

However, since you extend both Document and Folder, perhaps your actually need a mutually recursive type bound. By which I mean that in your solution, the expression

```
new MyFolder().findDocuments().get(0).getFolder()
```

is of type `Folder<MyDocument>`, not `MyFolder`. If it needs to be MyFolder, the generics get ugly:

```
//Folder, which holds zero or more documents
interface Folder<D extends Document<D, F>, F extends Folder<D, F>> {
    ArrayList<D> findDocuments();
}

// Document, contained within a folder
interface Document<D extends Document<D, F>, F extends Folder<D, F>> {
    F getFolder();
}
```

You can then implement:

```
class MyFolder implements Folder<MyDocument, MyFolder> {
    @Override
    public ArrayList<MyDocument> findDocuments() {
        return new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(new MyDocument()));
    }
}

class MyDocument implements Document<MyDocument, MyFolder> {
    @Override
    public MyFolder getFolder() {
        return new MyFolder();
    }
}
```

and now,

```
MyFolder folder = new MyFolder().findDocuments().get(0).getFolder();
```

compiles, too.

BTW, using `ArrayList` in an interface is quite restrictive, as the kludge when I wanted to use `Collections.singletonList` illustrates. You also (inadvertently?) deny yourself the services of `Collections.unmodifiableList` and friends. Usually, one therefore leaves the List implementation to the discretion of the implementor by declaring

```
List<D> findDocuments();
```

instead.

Comment: Yes, I expected the complete type-safe solution would be rather complex. I can see that providing both the `DocType` and `FolderType` as template parms for both the `Folder` and the `Document` classes makes things a little easier. Going the full distance to allow `getFolder()` to return the exact `MyFolder` type is complicated, but I see why Java needs all of it.

Fortunately, the resulting client code is pretty simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

The way you have it seems to be Ok for me, with the exception of a missing type parameters in the `Document` and `Folder` interfaces and the use of `ArrayList` (an implementation) instead of `List` (an interface).

```
interface Folder<T extends Document<T>>
{
    public List<T> findDocuments();

}

interface Document<T extends Document<T>>
{
    public Folder<T> getFolder();
}
```

Using the API is the best way to know, let's say we have an implementation of `Document` called `SpreadSheet`:

```
class SpreadSheet implements Document<SpreadSheet> {

    @Override
    public Folder<SpreadSheet> getFolder() {
        return new SpreadSheetFolder();
    }
}
```

And then you have a `Folder` implementation called `SpreadSheetFolder`:

```
class SpreadSheetFolder implements Folder<SpreadSheet>{

    @Override
    public List<SpreadSheet> findDocuments() {
        return asList(new SpreadSheet(), new SpreadSheet());
    }
}
```

Then when you use your API, you would do:

```
Document<SpreadSheet> d = new SpreadSheet();
Folder<SpreadSheet> folder = d.getFolder();
```

It works just fine.

Comment: +1 from me, but a minor quibble: you've got `findDocuments()` returning `ArrayList<T>` in the `Folder` interface, but `List<SpreadSheet>` in the `SpreadSheetFolder` class, which would be a compile-time error.

Comment: @DanielPryden Good catch! I was playing with it from editor itself and it is hard to spot when you have made errors. Thanks, I have corrected the answer.

Comment: This is probably the simplest solution. It has the small drawback that @meriton points out, though, that `getFolder()` does not return the exact client `SpreadSheetFolder` type, but only type `Folder<SpreadSheet>`. This might be okay, though.

Comment: @Loadmaster Allegedly `Folder` is an interface for exactly the purpose of not exposing specific implementations, as such, I would arguably consider this design better encapsulated and enforcing the reduction of coupling between the documents and specific implementations of the `Folder` interface. But hey, it wouldn't be the first time I am wrong ;-)

Comment: @edalorzo: True, and your solution is fine. But in this particular case I wanted the `Folder` and `Document` types to be implemented together as a pair, so therefore they should probably be more tightly coupled.